# Dotnet webapp templates have app.UseAuthorization() without app.UseAuthentication()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Almost all of the dotnet default templates have the line `app.UseAuthorization()` without `app.UseAuthentication()` in pipeline configuration. For example, inline is a webapp created in .net 6.0 by running `dotnet new webapp`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

The thing that intrigues me is, authorization can work only with authentication, so it is mandatory to have both `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()` in the pipeline. Also the order has to be exact i.e. `app.UseAuthentication()` must be followed by `app.UseAuthorization()`.

However, the pipeline created with default templates has only `app.UseAuthorization()`. Can someone shed some light on what might be the purpose behind adding just `app.UseAuthorization()` to the pipeline?

Comment: I am not sure but in the documentation, it is mentioned that When authorizing a resource that is routed using endpoint routing, this call must appear between the calls to app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(...) for the middleware to function correctly.

So it generates the code for it so that developers don't make mistakes. I would request the experts to comment

Comment: I see. So the nice exception which I get on developer exception page when I call an action method decorated with [Authorize] without properly setting up authentication and authorization is because of this middleware?

Comment: Check this thread: [The purpose to add app.UseAuthorization() middleware when using a default template to create a none-Authentication application](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38887)

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question.

Comment: @DurgaPrasad, glad to hear it did help resolve the problem. And I add it as an answer, hoping it can help other community members quickly fix similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: [The purpose to add app.UseAuthorization() middleware when using a default template to create a none-Authentication application](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38887)

*Starting in 3.1, endpoint routing replaced a few MVC constructs including replacing auth filters with the AuthorizationMiddleware. So you would need the middleware any time you happen to be using MVC. Particularly because you could have authorization rules that do not require a user to be authenticated. For instance, RequireHttpsAttribute is an auth filter that requires a resource is only allowed over a TLS connection. You could conceive of other auth requirements that are based on the HTTP request characteristics rather than the logged in user.*